# Mysql. Bind on unix socket: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, centos

Can't start mysql with:

```
130408 11:31:22 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Table 'plugin' is read only
130408 11:31:22 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130408 11:31:22  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130408 11:31:22  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130408 11:31:23  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 19514977
130408 11:31:23 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
130408 11:31:23 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
130408 11:31:23 [ERROR] Aborting

130408 11:31:23  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130408 11:31:28  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 19514977
130408 11:31:28 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
130408 11:31:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Another mysql is not runnig:

```
[root@triton667 etc]# ps ax | grep mysql
 9195 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep mysql
```

my.cnf:

```
    [mysqld]
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql
    socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    user=mysql
    tmpdir=/tmp
    # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
    symbolic-links=0
    max_allowed_packet=256M

    [mysqld_safe]

    log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
    pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Permissions on "/tmp" and "/var/lib/mysql" are 777/

Any suggestions?

**UPD1**:

```
[root@triton667 etc]# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

**UPD2**: 
plugin.MYD, plugin.MYI and plugin.frm are exists in /var/lib/mysql/mysql/.

Nothing running on port 3306.

mysql.sock does not exist. I tried to create it myself, but after restart it was removed.

mount(all rw):

```
[root@triton667 mysql]# mount
/dev/md1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/md0 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
```

This problem appeared today when I tried to clone my site on a subdomain.

Comment: run `mysql_upgrade` as suggested?

Comment: No.
touch /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock - Also does not work

Comment: Is there a plugin.MYD, plugin.MYI and plugin.frm file under /var/lib/mysql/mysql ?

Comment: Also, does the mysql.sock file exist in the /var/lib/mysql directory?

Comment: Is something already running on 3306 port?

Comment: Is your filesystem mounted read-only?

Comment: @user168508 If you've resolved the issue, please post the solution as an answer and [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) First make sure you delete the existing socket file using the rm command.

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

2) Kill all existing MySQL processes via the following command.

```
service mysql stop
```

3) Very important: Make sure the permission for the MySQL database directory under `/var/lib/` folder should be mysql:root

```
chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql
```

4) With the above information you should be able to start MySQL successfully and the socket file should be created successfully under the database directory.

```
service mysql start
```

Comment: I use a Ubuntu Server, and this didn't worked.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @Abhishek's answer combined with mysqld output(Can't use /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock) I managed to solve this with one command:

```
chown -R mysql:root /var/run/mysqld
```

---

Then it starts properly:

```
root@***:~# service mysql start
df: Warning: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
[ ok ] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld ..
[info] Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly..
```

Comment: Your welcome from the future :)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem can be caused by any condition that prevents the MySQL daemon from writing a socket file to the path `/var/lib/mysql`. The other answers, such as a read-only filesystem or incorrect directory ownership, address various reasons that MySQL may not be able to write to the socket.

Another possible reason is that `/var/lib/mysql` may have the incorrect SELinux context. You can diagnose this condition by checking for recent SELinux AVC denials after attempting to start the MySQL daemon:

`ausearch -m avc --start recent`

If SELinux is denying access to create the socket file, you will see an error message like this:

```
time->Thu Feb  2 03:46:27 2017
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1566106187.784:152): arch=c000004e syscall=49 success=no exit=-13 a0=4f a1=7ff3fd652e80 a2=6e a3=7fcd2d6523d40 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1820 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=994 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=994 sgid=994 fsgid=994 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="mysqld" exe="/usr/sbin/mysqld" subj=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1566106187.784:152): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=1820 comm="mysqld" name="mysql.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
```

To resolve an SELinux denial, try to restore the default context of the directory (your distribution should set the correct context of `mysqld_db_t` when you installed MySQL or MariaDB):

`restorecon -R -v -f /var/lib/mysql`

If you have customized the contexts on your system, fixing the problem is beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: On CentOS 7 with SELinux this is what I was facing and restoring the context fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you write, I would suggest that you check if your filesystem is mounted read-only.

> 130408 11:31:22 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /var/lib/mysql /usr/libexec/mysqld: Table 'plugin' is read only

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the other answers to resolve the issue. It appears that when i set selinux to permissive: `setenforce 0` I could start the server.

I then amended the sock directory `/var/lib/mysql` granting selinux permissions to the directory:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/var/lib/mysql(/.*)?"
restorecon -R -v -f /var/lib/mysql
```

Once done, i enable selinux using `setenforce 1` started the mysql service and all was well.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

While the [selected answer](https://serverfault.com/a/497203/33193) might do the trick, I had no luck with it. Only after following [this suggestion](https://www.webhosting.uk.com/forums/forum/technical-support/linux-dedicated-servers/8718-can%C2%92t-start-server-bind-on-unix-socket-permission-denied) to kill mysql processes I could then reboot and mysql was up.

Interestingly enough, in my case mysql was up after powering down and up again, but not after a reboot from the command line (and would not be started. except power off and on again)

Otherwise the symptoms were the same.

MulMic